# Multidimensional SSAS cube: using local (danish) characters

Tags: ssas, culture

I have a dimension called dim_Person. I have values in the Name column (or attribute) which contains danish characters. I have found out that if I have two rows in my datawarehouse table with the same name, but spelled in danish and english, I will get an error. For example:

```
Surrogate_Key FirstName
1             Ægir
2             Aegir
```

I will get an error, saying that my FirstName attribute with the value 'Aegir' fails as the cube cannot insert a dublicate key row.

```
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing: Table: 'dim_Person', Column: 'FirstName', Value: 'Aegir'. The attribute is 'First Name'.
```

I have figured out that if I change all 'Ægir' to 'Aegir' (or vice versa) in my datawarehouse source table I have no problems processing the dimension. But if the two names co-exists it will not process.

I assume that behind the scenes, all values are stored in an (for the developer) unknown table. It is as if it looks up: Does the value 'Aegir' exists? and get a 'no it does not' returned. Then it tries to insert the value, but the 'Ae' is converted to an 'Æ' (or vice versa) and then it fails.

For the moment I have converted all special characters in the source table to english characters, but I would like to know: is there a way I can set up my project so the two names can co-exists in the same dimension?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with Æ and get the same error message when trying to process the SSAS dimension.  In my case, the problem is the Danish city of:  Vedbæk

And I solved it:  I changed the collation property (Properties -> KeyColumns -> [open up the attribute] -> Collation) from Accent Sensitive to Binary 2